# Не реагирует изменить для определенной строки в gridView asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, gridview

Есть GridView. Он привязан к БД. Вроде все везде работает, подтягивается, изменяется, обновляется. Но в определенной строке **Изменить** не работает(как будто не реагирует). Я на этой строке нажимаю кнопку **Изменить** и оно не реагирует никак. На других строках данных кнопка Изменить работает, именно на этой строке не работает. БД(sql-server) думаю тут не причем. В чем может быть ошибка, куда копать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали ли Вы пользоваться отладкой?

Comment: @Bald, у меня в .cs файле нет кода почти. Я еще и делал отладку. Там все в норме.

Comment: Действие изменения ваше или нет? Неужели нельзя отладить?